# Adding space between the names in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Having an excel file as below:
[image]

I was concatenate first,middle and final name using below formula.

```
=CONCATENATE(A4," ",B4," ",C4)
```

But i need to update this formula and if there is no middle name, then the space needs to be single. and if there is a middle name.Then there should be space between both first and last name.

EXPECTED:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If available, use `TEXTJOIN()` and make sure to have the 2nd parameter set to TRUE (by default), e.g.:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,A2:C2)
```

You could now nest this in a `BYROW()` lambda helper if you feel like it (or just copy the formula down).

If `TEXTJOIN()` is not available, incorporate `TRIM()` which will get rid of double, trailing and/or leading spaces, e.g.: `=TRIM(CONCATENATE(A2," ",B2," ",C1))`. Please do note that `CONCATENATE()` in itself is redundant if one uses the ampersand to piece text together:

```
=TRIM(A2&" "&B2&" "&C2)
```

Answer (score 0):

So test A4, B4 and C4 to make sure none are blank:

```
=if(A4="","",A4&" ")&if(B4="","",B4&" ")&if(C4="","",C4&" ")
```

You could just test B4 as a minimum, but being thorough saves having to go back and edit later...

Edit:
Also you could take the opportunity to capitalise as necessary:

```
PROPER(IF(A4="","",A4&" ")&IF(B4="","",B4&" ")&IF(C4="","",C4&" "))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use an 'if' function inside your concat:

=concat(a4, " ", b4, if(b4<>"", " ", ""), c4)